# Aggregation pipeline addToSet returning a set of arrays on nested array records instead of a single array

Tags: mongodb, pipeline, aggregation

Goal:  For the fastest-possible queries with C#.NET and MongoDB v4.0, perform multiple distinct(s) utilizing a single aggregation pipeline style query on a document with nested array records and return a flattened out set.

Current-Problem:   For first level document entries it works great, unexpected results when running the distinct on the nested array records.

Example Document:

```
{  
  "title" : "Movie A",
  "released": 1984,
  "minutes" : 90,
  "category": "SciFi",
  "cost": 24000000,
  "gross": 48000000,
  "rated": "PG",
  "score": 3.4,
  "cast" : [
     {
     "name": "Buzz",
     "gender":"M",
     "age": 28,
     "country": "USA",
     "role": "Leading",
     "award" : "Golden Globe",
     "pay": 500000
     },
     {
     "name": "Sally",
     "gender":"F",
     "age": 21,
     "country": "Austrailia",
     "role": "Supporting",
     "award" : "Academy",
     "pay": 300000
     }
  ]
}
```

How to Build with Mongo Client:

use ;

```
db.createCollection("movies");

db.movies.insertOne({ "title" : "Movie A",  "released": 1984,  "minutes": 90,  "category": "SciFi",  "cost": 24000000,  "gross": 48000000,  "rated": "PG",  "score": 3.4,  "cast" : [ { "name": "Buzz",  "gender":"M", "age": 28, "country": "USA", "role": "Leading", "award" : "Golden Globe", "pay": 500000 }, { "name": "Sally", "gender":"F", "age": 21, "country": "Austrailia", "role": "Supporting",  "award": "Academy",  "pay": 300000  } ]});

db.movies.insertOne({ "title" : "Movie B",  "released": 1986,  "minutes": 120, "category": "Horror",  "cost": 28000000,  "gross": 40000000,  "rated": "R",  "score": 4.4,  "cast" : [ { "name": "Ryan",  "gender":"M", "age": 55, "country": "England", "role": "Leading", "award": "Oscar Nomination", "pay": 100000 }, { "name": "Sally", "gender":"F", "age": 23, "country": "Austrailia", "role": "Supporting",  "award": "Academy",  "pay": 300000  } ]});

db.movies.insertOne({ "title" : "Movie C",  "released": 1988,  "minutes": 106, "category": "Drama", "cost": 38000000,  "gross": 45000000,  "rated": "PG13",  "score": 2.4,  "cast" : [ { "name": "Pat",  "gender":"F", "age": 42, "country": "Ireland", "role": "Supporting", "award": "Irish", "pay": 350000 }, { "name": "Gene", "gender":"F", "age": 44, "country": "France", "role": "Leading",  "award": "Independent",  "pay": 280000  } ]});
```

C#.NET Code w/ Mongo v 4.0 and 2.5 Driver version

```
MongoDatabase mdb = Mongo.Controller.Instance.getDB();
var collection = mdb.GetCollection("movies");
var match = new BsonDocument
   {
     {
        "$match",
         new BsonDocument
            {
              {  "released", new BsonDocument
                  {
                     {"$gte", 1984},
                     { "$lte", 1988}
                  }
              }
           }
       }
   };

  var group = new BsonDocument
     {
         { "$group",
             new BsonDocument  {
                                 { "_id",  0},                                          
                                 { "categoryDistinct", new BsonDocument  {  { "$addToSet", "$category" }  }},
                                 { "ratedDistinct", new BsonDocument  {  { "$addToSet", "$rated" }  }},                                           
                                 { "countryDistinct", new BsonDocument  {  { "$addToSet", "$cast.country" }  }},
                                 { "awardDistinct", new BsonDocument  {  { "$addToSet", "$cast.award" }  }}                                          
                   }
            }
       };


   var pipeline = new[] { match, group };
   var args = new AggregateArgs();
   args.Pipeline = pipeline;
   args.AllowDiskUse = true;

   var results = collection.Aggregate(args).ToList();


   foreach (var obj in results)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
      }
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : 0, "categoryDistinct" : ["Drama", "Horror", "SciFi"], "ratedDistinct" : ["PG13", "R", "PG"], "countryDistinct" : [["Ireland", "France"], ["England", "Austrailia"], ["USA", "Austrailia"]], "awardDistinct" : [["Irish", "Independent"], ["Oscar Nomination", "Academy"], ["Golden Globe", "Academy"]] }
```

Notes:   categoryDistinct and ratedDistinct are coming back as I would expect, but the countryDistinct and awardDistinct are not, they are coming back in a nested sub array record form.

Desired Output :  countryDistinct should have been

```
["Austrailia,England,France,Ireland,USA"] 
                   awardDistinct should have been: ["Academy","Golden Globe","Independent","Irish","Oscar Nomination"];
              (I know I didn't specify a sort anywhere so if you can give a pointer that will not impact speed, that would be greatly appreciated.
```

Any pointers on how to do this efficiently -- speed consciously would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
 Shane

Comment: You need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) your arrays first before you can get the "unique" individual values from "inside the array".

Comment: Thanks Neil I was leaning toward that solution or facet, but really didn't know how to structure it.   Here's what I was able to come up with that made this work correctly:                    var unwindCast = new BsonDocument
                {
                    {"$unwind", "$cast" }           
                };
 
                var pipeline = new[] { match, unwindCast, group };    So basically I had to unwind the top-level array of "cast", not cast.country or cast.award and that was the nugget of information I needed.